# Image algorith: draw line between two borders of a closed shape

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr

I have a set of shapes, which are detected from characters, like this:

[image: Original]

Is there an algorithm (i wrote my code in python) which returns a single line between the border of the shape by a given precision to output it like this?

[image: Solution]

Thanks for help, Mattia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at the [Medial Axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis) algorithm. You can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156080/medial-axis-transform-implementation).